How can I update this Jetpack Compose chart?
So I have a composable function which shows a trip count comparison between months. The difference is shown on a chart graph, which I got from a github repository.
I checked, and every time, the MonthComparison changes, the composable gets called, but unfortunately the chart is not updating itself with the new values.
This chart composable needs a simple List parameter. Does this mean, the first time it get's a list, it shows that state, and won't respond to list changes?
Comparison chart function
@Composable
fun showChartSection(monthComparison: MonthComparison?)
{
    showSubTitles(text = stringResource(id = R.string.MonthlyCompare))
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(0.dp, 10.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        showParagraphText(text = stringResource(id = R.string.MonthComparisonByTrip))
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .width(180.dp)
            .height(180.dp)
            .padding(0.dp, 5.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp)
        )
        {
            val donutChartData = remember {
                mutableStateOf(
                    listOf(
                        DonutData(360f, secondarycolor)
                    )
                )
            }
            if(monthComparison != null)
            {
                donutChartData.value = listOf(
                    DonutData(monthComparison.currentMonthTripCount.toFloat(), secondarycolor),
                    DonutData(monthComparison.pastMonthTripCount.toFloat(), primarycolor)
                )
            }
            DonutChart(modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center),
                data = donutChartData.value)
        }
}

DonutChart's parameters
@Composable
fun DonutChart(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    type: DonutChartType = DonutChartType.Normal,
    data: List<DonutData>,
    style: DonutChartStyle = DonutChartStyle(),
    onSliceClick: ((DonutData)-> Unit)? = null
)

